# Store Locator mySQL Query with Locations having Varying Radii

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table of locations, each having an id, street, city, state, latitude, longitude, radius column. The radius for each location may vary, ie. 5, 10, 15, 20...(miles).

What I am after is a query that would give me a count(id) of all locations whose radius touches a given latitude & longitude coordinate.

I found the query below but have not figured out how to modify it to accommodate my needs. It takes a latitude, longitude, and fixed distance.

My guess is the key to getting what I am modifying (or removing) the Having clause.

My goal is to determine if any location's given radius touches the center.

```
SELECT
    `id`, `street`, `city`, `state`, `radius`, `longitude`, `latitude`,
    (
        6371 *
        acos(
            cos( radians( 41.257160 ) ) *
            cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) *
            cos(
                radians( `longitude` ) - radians( -95.995102 )
            ) +
            sin(radians(41.257160)) *
            sin(radians(`latitude`))
        )
    ) `distance`
FROM
    `shops`
HAVING
    `distance` < 25
ORDER BY
    `distance`
LIMIT
    25
```

I seemed to get results using "Having `distance` < `radius` but I question their accuracy. The latitude & longitude used in my query are close to 1801 S. 54th Street in Omaha NE.

Looking at the attached screen shot of results you can see the formula returns Arlington as 950 miles away, and Yuba City CA as 2182 Miles. In actuality, Arlington is about 694 miles (by car) and Yuba City CA is 1565 miles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seemingly had the query set to kilometers, not miles. Sorry

Comment: I wonder how I could get the total number of records returned in the recordset. I tried count(id) but it does not work